# Find executable path regardless if it is an alias or a command

Tags: php, shell, debian

I'm doing a bash script that has to run a php file. Usually it would be `php file.php`, but the server I'm running this script has many versions of php installed (Plesk server, many projects, different versions for each one...)

So, for the command line there are some aliases:

```
alias php7='/opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php'
alias php='/opt/plesk/php/8.0/bin/php'
```

I have read that the best ways of finding an executable would be using `type` or `command -v`, but in this case it doesn't output the path of the executable:

```
$ type php
php is aliased to `/opt/plesk/php/8.0/bin/php'
$ command -v php
alias php='/opt/plesk/php/8.0/bin/php'
```

I need to find the path to the `php` executable regardless if it is an alias, an actual executable or whatever. The problem is that right now, if I run `php file.php` in my script I get this:

```
$ ./test
./test: line 9: php: command not found
```

Any help? Thanks!!

Update: this is the content of the script I’m doing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SCRIPT_DIR="$( pwd )"
CLI_FILE="${SCRIPT_DIR}/ofw/vendor/cli/cli.php"

PHP_FILE="$( which php )"

if test -f "$CLI_FILE"; then
        php $CLI_FILE
else
        echo "ERROR: OFW CLI must be run in a OFW project folder."
fi
```

Comment: Not understanding what you want here? What is line 9 of your `test` binary? Provide the minimalistic, reproducible code possible so we can see your issue.

Comment: "_but in this case it doesn't output the path of the executable_" Not sure I understand this, but `/opt/plesk/php/8.0/bin/php` _is_ the path to the executable. What's the shebang in your script?

Comment: Also, you should always use the binary's **absolute path** in shell scripts as security best-practice. Without doing so means the script checks the environmental path variables for the binary, which can be modified.

Comment: Jaquarh, I have updated the question with the script I’m doing. It is something I just have started, be nice please :P brombeer, what I meant is that it doesn’t “just” output the path to the executable, there is also some extra text that I would need to get rid of.

Comment: I think that instead of `php $CLI_FILE` you can just run `$PHP_FILE $CLI_FILE`, unless I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Sorry Chris, I guess I was the one that didn’t explain myself. That PHP_FILE line is just a test. It wouldn’t work because as php is an alias, that PHP_FILE variable is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `./test` is a shell script, note that your aliases are not available to it.

Unless you really ask it to:

```sh
shopt -s expand_aliases
source ~/.bashrc         # or whatever file defines your aliases.

php file.php             # should now work
```

However, a simpler method is to add the php directory to the PATH of the script

```sh
PATH=/opt/plesk/php/8.0/bin/php:$PATH

php file.php
```

---

The generic approach. This assumes the user's shell is bash.

```sh
setupTool() {
    local tool=$1
    if ! [[ $tool =~ ^[[:alnum:]._-]+$ ]]; then
        echo "Malicious input: '$tool'" >&2
        return 1
    fi
    case "$( bash -ic "type -t $tool" )" in
        alias)
            shopt -s expand_aliases
            eval "$( bash -ic "alias $tool" )"
            ;;
        function)
            eval "$( bash -ic "declare -f $tool" )"
            ;;
        file|builtin|keyword)
            : ;; # no-op
        *)  echo "error: don't know about $tool" >&1
            return 1
            ;;
    esac
}

setupTool php || exit 1
php file.php
```

Comment: Hi Glenn, the first part would do the trick, but I’m trying to do this as “generic”, or “for anyone”, not my exact scenario. The second part wouldn’t work because, as I said, there are several php versions installed, so, which one should I add to the path?

Comment: "which one should I add to the path" -- The wrapper script has to know what PHP version the PHP script requires. That's really the purpose of a wrapper script: ensure the correct environment is set up to run the PHP code. You can't really do this "for anyone" because everyone's shell setup is unique.

Comment: Indeed, every environment will be different, that’s precisely the point of this question: how can I find out where exactly is the executable that a certain user “calls php”? In my case php is an alias that points to “ /opt/plesk/php/8.0/bin/php”, but on anothwr server php could be directly the executable, not an alias. So the simple question would be “if you run php, where is the executable file that fires up?” I don’t care if it is an alias, something in your path, the php executable itself… Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Hi! I read from mobile last time and I didn't see the code. That  setupTool function works perfectly. Thank you very much!!